# How to install a ceiling light fixture to a light box that just has 2 white wires coming from the ceiling?

Tags: electrical

[image: Light box 2 white wires]The house was built in 1957. There was a ceiling fan installed but the fan and light stopped working. My  husband uninstalled the ceiling fan while I was buying the new light fixture. I came home I seen the 2 white wires and thought that wasn't right. After a google search and youtube video I went back out and bought a voltage meter. Video said place red lead to wire black lead to metal box one of the white wires should read 120 volts. I get nothing from either wire doing this. My husband placed red lead to one white wire and the black lead to the other white wire just to see what it would do and it lit up 120 volts but didn't help me to know what I need to do. He thinks we should just pick one and move on but I'm scared of doing that. How else can I find out which white wire might be the hot wire?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: did you remember to turn on the wall switch?

Comment: @jsotola yes I did eventually turn the switch on and test the wires still nothing.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I added a photo best I could get.